# React set in useState only running once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I think I'm not understanding something fundamental about React hooks or maybe even just React in general.
I'm setting values from the backend.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
      rentAmount: props.values.zestimates.rent_zestimate.toLocaleString('en-US'),
      monthlyPayment: props.values.zestimates.rent_zestimate.toLocaleString('en-US'),
      vacancyAmount: (props.values.zestimates.rent_zestimate * 0.1).toLocaleString('en-US'),
      vacancyRate: 10,
      repairsAmount: (props.values.zestimates.rent_zestimate * 0.1).toLocaleString('en-US'),
      repairsRate: 10,
      propertyManagementAmount: (props.values.zestimates.rent_zestimate * 0.1).toLocaleString('en-US'),
      propertyManagementRate: 10,
    })
```

The user can change rentAmount from a textbox as well as change the rates from other textboxes and what I want is for 3 different values to update once rentAmount has changed but I'm running into an issue where the last declared setValues() is the only one to run.

I have 5 useEffects set up (probably not the way to do this but kind of stumbled across React Hooks halfway through this hobby project) but I'm focusing on just 3 for this question

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, vacancyAmount: formatter.format(values.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, '') * values.vacancyRate/100).replace('$', '')})
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [values.vacancyRate, values.rentAmount])

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, repairsAmount: formatter.format(values.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, '') * values.repairsRate/100).replace('$', '')})
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [values.repairsRate, values.rentAmount])

  useEffect(() => {
    setValues({ ...values, propertyManagementAmount: formatter.format(values.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, '') * values.propertyManagementRate/100).replace('$', '')})
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [values.propertyManagementRate, values.rentAmount])
```

My issue is, the last setValues for propertyManagementAmount runs just fine when rentAmount is updated but the other 2 don't run and I don't understand why.

Comment: might be because the value is overridden by the last useEffect. Try using the callback version of useEffect. e.g. `setValues((value) => ({ ...values, repairsAmount: formatter.format(values.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, '') * values.repairsRate/100).replace('$', '')}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep... this is slightly confusing.

When you run `setValues` the `values` property is what it was on the last render. So if you did this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue(value + 1);
  setValue(value + 1);
  setValue(value + 1);
}, []);
```

`value` will be `2` after the first render. Because on each `setValue` execution `value` is `1` from the last render. Also bonus, you should include `value` as a dependency to `useEffect` which will cause an infinite re-render (because `value` is being changed by the `useEffect` and `value` also causes it to run)... the solution to your problem also fixes this.

If you did this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  setValue(value => value + 1);
  setValue(value => value + 1);
  setValue(value => value + 1);
}, []);
```

Then `value` will be `4`, as the function form of `useState` gets the last value set. Also, `value` does not need to be listed as a dependency of `useEffect` which solves the issue mentioned above.

So just change your:

```
setValues({ ...values, vacancyAmount...
```

to

```
setValues(values => { ...values, vacancyAmount...
```

Documentation on this is [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, with your answer and kkesley's comment I got it sorted. I did have to use parenthesis like kkesley's comment suggested. Also, would give ya an upvote but still don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted if it is correct please, glad it worked! I hope you understand why the function form works and the value form doesn't. Ask if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all of them in one `useEffect` like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValues(prevValues => ({
      ...prevValues,
      vacancyAmount: formatter
        .format(
          (prevValues.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "") *
            prevValues.vacancyRate) /
            100
        )
        .replace("$", ""),
      repairsAmount: formatter
        .format(
          (prevValues.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "") *
            prevValues.repairsRate) /
            100
        )
        .replace("$", ""),
      propertyManagementAmount: formatter
        .format(
          (prevValues.rentAmount.toString().replace(/,/g, "") *
            prevValues.propertyManagementRate) /
            100
        )
        .replace("$", "")
    }));
  },[values.rentAmount]);
```